# The model could not be saved: Access Denied. (COleException 0x80030005)

Tags: revit-api

I'm still a relatively new Revit user, but I was able to complete the My first plugin tutorial.

https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/tsarticles/ts/7I2bC1zUr4VjJ3U31uM66K.html .  I'm currently attempting to build a custom Add-In that will Save a local copy of a Revit file to a targeted local folder. I've been able to get my Add-In to load into Revit, but I get the error in the title when I attempt to launch.   I've generated my GUID from an online generator.  Source code and manifest were pulled from ChatGPT.  Could this be an issue with privileges on my account or the rights associated with the Revit version in use or my code?  I haven't been able to find much on this specific error in the Revit environment online so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;

namespace SaveAs
{

    [Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
    [Regeneration(RegenerationOption.Manual)]
    public class Class1 : IExternalCommand
    {
        public Result Execute(
            ExternalCommandData commandData,
            ref string message,
            ElementSet elements)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the active document
                Document doc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;

                // Specify the file path for saving
                string filePath = "C:\\DocStorage";

                // Save the document with the SaveAs method
                SaveAsOptions options = new SaveAsOptions();
                doc.SaveAs(filePath, options);

                return Result.Succeeded;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                message = ex.Message;
                return Result.Failed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RevitAddIns>
 <AddIn Type="Command">
       <Name>SaveAs</Name>
       <FullClassName>SaveAs.Class1</FullClassName>
       <Text>SaveAs</Text>
       <Description>Places the Group at Particular Point</Description>
       <VisibilityMode>AlwaysVisible</VisibilityMode>
       <Assembly>C:\Save\SaveAs\SaveAs\bin\Debug\net6.0\SaveAs.dll</Assembly>
       <AddInId>69e911ac-532a-42a2-83f1-8a72084289b9</AddInId>
    <VendorId>RT</VendorId>
    <VendorDescription>RT, Inc, www.RT.com</VendorDescription>
 </AddIn>
</RevitAddIns>
```

I was able to get the plugin to initialize and appear on Revit taskbar, but I'm stuck at this point.  I've tried different save locations/folders, but haven't had any success. I've also given myself full control of Temp folder, as I was reading in AutoDesk articles that this could cause an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Revit API! The code you show seems to be trying to save a Revit `RVT` document to the root folder of the `C:` drive. Afaik, that requires pretty special privileges that are normally not given. Have you tried to save the project manually to that location in the end user interface? That will probably cause the same or an equivalent error. Try saving the file to your personal user folder instead.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are only specifying the path where you would like to save your file, without including the file name. This makes Revit angry.

Thus, please modify your `SaveAs()` to be:

```
doc.SaveAs(filePath + $"\\{doc.Title}.rvt", options)
```